# How to copy a file to a directory in DOS, and create directories if necessary?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How can I copy a file using DOS commands into a directory structure that may not yet exist? I need to be able to force the creation of the directory path to the target file location if that location doesn't already exist.

For example, there is already a file.txt in this location:

```
C:\file.txt
```

And I want to copy it to

```
C:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\file.txt
```

but at this time

```
C:\example\
```

and all the subdirectories may or may not yet exist.

Basically, I am looking for a "copy and create the target path if necessary" command. What would you recommend is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Is this question actually about DOS (or MS-DOS), or is it about the command line found in NT based Windows versions (2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, Server)?

Comment: I meant the DOS-like Windows CLI. What do you recommend is the best way to describe "DOS-like Windows CLI" for the post title?

Comment: Generally, I would use `Windows command line` in the title/body, along with the tags [tag:windows] and [tag:command-line] (note that [tag:cmd.exe] is a tag synonym of [tag:command-line]). The tag [tag:ms-dos] should be removed; and the tag [tag:dos] should not be used at all under any circumstances.

Comment: However, in this case, with the existing/accepted answers being for DOS/MS-DOS, you may as well leave it as-is. For future reference, DOS is/should be interpreted as the operating system(s). While the Windows command line is based on them, there are some notable differences.

Comment: you can call it the cmd prompt

Comment: Why was this migrated from StackOverflow? This is about programming, so doesn't it belong there?

Comment: @NewSites it's about general shell usage and not specifically about programming. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You call it the command prompt. It's not appropriate to call it DOS because [DOS (actually command.com) and cmd.exe are very different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386) and has different capabilities and syntax

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yeah, that's [**xcopy**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289483). Here's what it'll look like:

```
xcopy file.txt c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\file.txt
```

XCOPY info at

- [Commandlinefu xcopy](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/matching/xcopy/eGNvcHk=/sort-by-votes)
- [TechNet Xcopy Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx)
- [Wikipedia xcopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY)

You might also want to look into [ROBOCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy), in the XP resource kit and standard in Vista, Windows 7, and Server 2008.

```
robocopy . c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file file.txt
```

Comment: xcopy is fine if you don't need to also rename your file. If you do, unfortunately xcopy will ask you whether the destination is a directory or a filename and there is no command-line switch to specify "it's a file".

Comment: See the other answer - use a preceding `echo f | ` with xcopy to answer this prompt automatically.

Comment: Note that there should be a slash character, `\`, on the end of the  destination path. Otherwise the command will prompt the user about whether the destination is a dir or a file if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 22):

I tried using something like:

```
xcopy file.txt c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\file.txt
```

But it would ask me if it was a file or directory. Since I had that in a batch file with 40000 files, it would be impractical. This solution only solves partially my problem: it creates the directory structure, but it requires user interaction.
I found the solution to my problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283312/batch-file-asks-for-file-or-folder

Which is basically to add a "*" at the end of the destination file:

```
xcopy file.txt c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\file.txt*
```

EDIT: as pointed by @romkyns, it may have undesired results if you have files that have the same name plus something else (like 'file.txt.bak'). In the same thread posted above, another solution that works is piping "echo f" to your command:

```
echo f | xcopy file.txt c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\file.txt
```

Where you should substitute the "f" for whatever letter your system uses for file, in case you're using it in another language..

Comment: Which only works if there is no `file.txt.bak` in the directory, of course. Still, this might work in some scenarios.

Comment: @romkyns true. a few months after I posted this, I faced myself with the same problem and did the "echo f" solution, it works great as well. Editing my answer...

Comment: With `echo f | `, you no longer need the trailing `*`.

Comment: The second filename is redundant in case that it is the same. "xcopy file.txt c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\" will work as long as the trailing slash in the directory is there (otherwise it asks if either a file or a directory weas meant).

Comment: Just use `xcopy file.txt "c:\example\new\path\to\copy\of\file\"` - it doesn't require interactoion.

Answer (score 4):

Whether using `copy` or `xCopy`, in order to avoid an error from `copy` or a prompt from `xCopy`, test for the existence of the needed folder and create it if necessary:

```
if not exist "NewPath" MkDir "NewPath"
copy "[path\]file.ext" "NewPath[\NewFileName.ext]"
```

or combine the commands with `&&` on one command line:

```
if not exist "NewPath" MkDir "NewPath" && copy "[path\]file.ext" "NewPath[\NewFileName.ext]"
```

The same thing can be done with `move` instead of `copy`. I learned about this technique from a [*StackOverflow* answer](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/7264736/windows-batch-move-to-directory-that-may-not-exist#7268357) about how to do it with `move`.

Answer (score 3):

DOS, wow! Anyway you use the [XCOPY](http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm) command.

Comment: 4 years on: yup. DOS we all still use it even though PowerShell exists..

Comment: Its 2021. We have PowerShell 7, brand new Terminal app, WSL2 — and we still use `xcopy` to do stuff.