# Win7 command-line: How to copy a file and create the missing subtree

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I have a number of files I need copied to different networked locations.  However, it is a regular occurrence that the sub-directories need to be created.  I considered building an app to do this, but I'd rather not "re-invent the wheel" if I don't need to.

An example would be as follows:

Copying:

```
C:\ProjectFolder\Project\WCB\2010\CA\ON\EmployeeReport.aspx.cs
```

To:

```
\\Server1\Downloads\Patches\Web\Project\
```

would end up copying the file to:

```
\\Server1\Downloads\Patches\Web\Project\WCB\2010\CA\ON\EmployeeReport.aspx.cs
```

(because "Project" is common in both paths, that's the starting point where we'd need to create the new path.)

Any suggestions?

-- Post Update: Sorry, it seems this is a duplicate of [How to copy a file to a directory in DOS, and create directories if necessary?](https://superuser.com/questions/119263/how-to-copy-a-file-to-a-directory-in-dos-and-create-directories-if-necessary)

The answer, although there isn't an automated way of doing this (maybe I'll write that utility after all) is using XCOPY:

```
XCOPY C:\ProjectFolder\Project\WCB\2010\CA\ON\EmployeeReport.aspx.cs \\Server1\Downloads\Patches\Web\Project\WCB\2010\CA\ON\EmployeeReport.aspx.cs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use XCOPY, as suggested in the updated post.  XCOPY does a fine job of creating the necessary directory tree on the networked server.